# How to execute code separately with the same Button

Tags: c#, button

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    TcpClient Client = new TcpClient();
    Client.Connect(IP, 5550);
    Stream MessageStream = Client.GetStream();
    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

    void SendServerMessage(string Message)
    {
        byte[] encodedMessage = encoder.GetBytes(Message);

        MessageStream.Write(encodedMessage, 0, encodedMessage.Length);
        MessageStream.Flush();

        Client.Close();
    }

    SendServerMessage(textBox2.Text);   
}
```

I would like that when I click the button the first time that everything executes and when I click the button the second time that only SendServerMessage() executes.

Comment: use a state machine for that.

Comment: What about when you click the button a third time?

Comment: You could use a class level variable to keep track of the number of button clicks.

Comment: You need to keep your TcpClient variable as a class property, and then just check in btnSend_Click if it is null or not. If it is null, create it and call SendServerMessage, if not just call SendServerMessage. Also, there's no need to have SendServerMessage as a function inside btnSend_Click, especially since it uses objects out of it's own internal scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your TcpClient as a class property then you can just check if it is null and then create it if needed.

I restructured your code to separate out each different functionality you have going on. Here is the wiki article for [Modular programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming). This is a good practice to follow to make your code cleaner and more maintainable.

```
private TcpClient client { get; set; }
private string ipAddressString = "127.0.0.1";
private int port = 5550;

private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddressString);
    TcpClient client = getConnection(ipAddress);

    sendServerMessage(client, textBox2.Text);
}

private TcpClient getConnection(IPAddress ipAddress)
{
    if (client == null)
        client = new TcpClient();
    if (!client.Connected)
        client.Connect(ipAddress, port);
    return client;
}

private void sendServerMessage(TcpClient client, string message)
{
    Stream messageStream = client.GetStream();
    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] encodedMessage = encoder.GetBytes(message);

    messageStream.Write(encodedMessage, 0, encodedMessage.Length);
    messageStream.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the secound time i click the button it should not connect to the server twice and the client should not close

Comment: @SinOfficial That's an easy change then, just don't do client.Close() and only connect if not already connected. I'll update my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Blake Thingstad. Here is the code i used:

```
private TcpClient client { get; set; }
    private string ipAddressString = "127.0.0.1";
    private int port = 5550;

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddressString); 
        if (client == null)
        {
            TcpClient client = connect(ipAddress);
        }
        sendServerMessage(client, textBox2.Text);
    }

    private TcpClient connect(IPAddress ipAddress)
    { 
        client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(ipAddress, port);
        return client;
    }

    private void sendServerMessage(TcpClient client, string message)
    {
        Stream messageStream = client.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] encodedMessage = encoder.GetBytes(message);

        messageStream.Write(encodedMessage, 0, encodedMessage.Length);
        messageStream.Flush();
    }
```

The difference is that i asked in btnSend_Click for client = null